# Preferred approach to develop simple motion game with Kinect

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect, game-engine

I wish to start a game development for windows PC using Kinect V2 sensor. The game concept is to record the users walking distance from a certain point.

As I am very new in gaming so I need to have few details before start this development:

1- What is the preferred way/ technology to develop Windows Game with Kinect V2 capabilities?

2- Can I use my .Net experience (C#, XAML) in this game development?

3- What plugins, SDKs, framework required to develop game?

4- If uses WPF+XAML then should I be able to create a setup for easy going installations to the client?

Please pardon me as I am new to Game development and looking for suggestions here!

Comment: A suggestion: see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

1- What is the preferred way/ technology to develop Windows Game with Kinect V2 capabilities?

Ans => You can use unity. Microsoft Provides kinect plug in for unity

2- Can I use my .Net experience (C#, XAML) in this game development?

Ans => You can code with C# in unity.

3- What plugins, SDKs, framework required to develop game?

Ans => Depends on what type game you want to develop. As for your interest, I want mention some creating coding framework such as [Processing](https://processing.org/) , [Cinder](http://libcinder.org/). You will find tons of plugins or assets in [Unity Asset Store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/).

4- If uses WPF+XAML then should I be able to create a setup for easy going installations to the client?

Ans => :-?

Well, suggestions for you.

1. Start Learning Unity. Complete [these](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules) tutorials.
2. [Official Unity plugin for Kinect v2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5c3b67b6-3fe2-4789-b2df-eb63419e7ab6/kinect-for-windows-v2-sdk-now-available?forum=kinectv2sdk).